How to pass a structure pointer within two function (both not main)
I want to pass a pointer that point to a structure from function A to function B where the structure was declared in function A, is that possible?
void func1() {
    typedef struct {
        int x;
        int y;
    }NumSet;

    NumSet* nPtr1, nStructure;
    nPtr1 = &nStructure;

    nPtr1->x = 5;
    nPtr1->y = 10;

    printf("%d %d\n", nPtr1->x, nPtr1->y);
}

void func2(NumSet *nPtr2) {
    int sum;

    sum = nPtr2->x + nPtr2->y;

    printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d", nPtr2->x, nPtr2->y, sum);
}

I know if declare the structure as global structure will makes job easy but I just wondering is there any methods that can bypass these kind of limits.

No, you would have to redefine the struct in func2().

OT: don't write NumSet* nPtr1, nStructure;, it's confusing, rather write NumSet* nPtr1; and NumSet nStructure; on separate lines. Both are equivalent, but latter is more readable.

Please clarify the intended use of this combination. Do you expect the struct to be passed around various functions, or is its existence for the sole use of func2().

The variable nStructure goes out of scope when func1() terminates, meaning func1() is effectively a no-op.

@Fe2O3 The structure should be passed around various functions, but it's only defined for one time, which is inside the func1().

The declaration of a struct must be visible anyplace it is used.
So your only option is to move the declaration out of the function.

Not quite the only option...

@trojanfoe The prototype for func2 needs the definition of NumSet, so it has to be at file scope.

No it doesn't; he could redefine it in func2().

@trojanfoe And that definition will only be visible inside the function, not the function's prototype, so the could will not compile.

Indeed; he'd have to pass the pointer as void* and cast it back, which is stupid for many reasons, but still possible.

@trojanfoe: It is not possible to redefine a structure type within a translation unit and use it to access an object defined with the original definition with behavior defined by the C standard. Per C 2018 6.2.7 1, the same definition made in two different translation units defines compatible types but not so for within one translation unit. Using the type defined in func2 to access an object defined with the type defined in func1 would violate the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7.

"Works" is not the same thing as actually reliably works.

Move the definition of the type NumSet out of the function so that it is visible throughout the translation unit.
Modify func1 to:

Allocate space for the structure, as with NumSet *nPtr = malloc(sizeof *nPtr);.
Provide the address of that space to the routine that calls it, as by returning it as the return value of the function or by storing the address in a pointer passed by the caller.

Modify the calling routine to take the address provided by func1 and pass it to func2.
You should also make arrangements to release the memory when it is no longer needed, as by calling free.
Example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} NumSet;


NumSet *func1(void)
{
    NumSet *nPtr1 = malloc(sizeof *nPtr1);
    if (!nPtr1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    nPtr1->x = 5;
    nPtr1->y = 10;

    printf("%d %d\n", nPtr1->x, nPtr1->y);

    return nPtr1;
}


void func2(NumSet *nPtr2)
{
    int sum;

    sum = nPtr2->x + nPtr2->y;

    printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d.\n", nPtr2->x, nPtr2->y, sum);
}


int main(void)
{
    NumSet *p = func1();
    func2(p);
    free(p);
}

